# Android SDK ADT plugin! Gives error on installing VIA install new software

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I know this question has been asked a number of time but i went and did evenrythgn suggested i am using Mac 10.6.8, Ecllipse 3.7.0 and http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

and i get this error

```
`Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 3.7.0.I20101028-1441 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.0.I20101028-1441)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Runtime 3.6.100.v20100628 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.100.v20100628)
    Core Runtime 3.7.0.v20110110 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0.v20110110)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EMF Common 2.7.0.v20110605-0747 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.7.0.v20110605-0747)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EMF Common 2.7.0.v20110912-0920 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.7.0.v20110912-0920)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EMF Common 2.7.0.v20120127-1122 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.7.0.v20120127-1122)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v20100923-9fF7JHAiFsAuq4Goz-NCfThFOyVEwz0z0Pmu4 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.0.v20100923-9fF7JHAiFsAuq4Goz-NCfThFOyVEwz0z0Pmu4)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.0.v20101022-9TBTFsGFwgqdN7ZkIU1WURQ]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.7.0.v20101022-9TBTFsGFwgqdN7ZkIU1WURQ (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.7.0.v20101022-9TBTFsGFwgqdN7ZkIU1WURQ)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.100.v20100628]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Project SDK 3.7.0.v20100629-7Q7t-DPX2naDL1jfutmm2idmoY-eH81sz-yIoQxy-Yeup (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group 3.7.0.v20100629-7Q7t-DPX2naDL1jfutmm2idmoY-eH81sz-yIoQxy-Yeup)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0.v20100923-9fF7JHAiFsAuq4Goz-NCfThFOyVEwz0z0Pmu4]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse SDK 3.7.0.I20101028-1441 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.0.I20101028-1441)
    To: org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group [3.7.0.v20100629-7Q7t-DPX2naDL1jfutmm2idmoY-eH81sz-yIoQxy-Yeup]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.3.0.v201105101529 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.0.v201105101529)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.3.1.v201108191312 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.1.v201108191312)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.3.2.v201201041522 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.2.v201201041522)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)`
```

Have tired everything but cant get thru this any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** package instead of the Eclipse Classic (SDK). The SDK build doesn't include the Indigo release repository that is needed to download some of the plugins that ADT requires.